# Dynamic Download Button

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

Hi I have a problem with a download button in my Shiny APP. I have created the button dynamically when the corresponding DF has been created. Now I have the problem that the download doesn't work. If I created the button directly the download works. 
I did the same with a reset function and everything works here. 
Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

This is the Button Code in the UI:

```
column(3, offset = 0, uiOutput("download.action", style = "text-align: center;"))
```

and my Server code looks like this:

```
    output$download.action <- renderUI({
      div(style = "display:inline-block;width:0%;", actionButton("downloadData", "Download", icon = icon("download"), 
      style = " 
         flex-grow: 1;
        display: inline-block;
        background-color:#999;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: 300;
        border: 1px dash transparent;
        letter-spacing: 0.98pt;
        border-color:#00245d;"))
    })

    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
        paste("test.xlsx")
      },
      content = function(file) {
        write.xlsx(test3, file, row.names = FALSE)
      }
    )
  })
```

When I create the Button directly everything works fine.

Shiny gives no Error Messages. Only the Button didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace `actionButton` with `downloadButton`.

```
output$download.action <- renderUI({
    div(style = "display:inline-block;width:0%;", downloadButton("downloadData", "Download", icon = icon("download"), 
                                                               style = " 
                                                               flex-grow: 1;
                                                               display: inline-block;
                                                               background-color:#999;
                                                               text-decoration: none;
                                                               font-weight: 300;
                                                               border: 1px dash transparent;
                                                               letter-spacing: 0.98pt;
                                                               border-color:#00245d;"))
  })
```